# How to use variables in draw?

Tags: tikz-pgf, csvsimple

I want to read in a `.csv` file and draw each line as a point (x,y) with his color (r,g,b). I managed to set the points and the drawing part is fine except for the color. How can I use my variables out of my `.csv` file in the draw-method?

**EDIT:** Draw is used the way I thought it was supposed to, I got an error for no reason ( }; was too much, looks like my face when realizing my fault) and now it works (thx to percusse)

```
    \begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
    x,y,r,g,b
    1,4,5,1,255
    2,3,123,55,55
    3,5,6,121,43
    4,1,47,93,0
    5,3,43,57,83
    \end{filecontents*}

    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{csvsimple}
    \usepackage{tikz}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \csvreader[head to column names]{data.csv}{}{
        \definecolor{tmpcolor}{RGB}{\r, \g, \b};
    \draw[fill=tmpcolor] (\x, \y) circle(1mm);
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

**Important**
We need an intermediate step before writing color to draw because fill={rgb:red, ...} mixed all given by their ratio. So fill={rgb:red, 0;green, 0;blue, 0} triggers an arithmetic error and won't result in black color. Other ratios result in colors different to the RGB Codecolors...

Comment: The third option works for me without any problems.

Comment: For some curious reason it now works without changes.

Comment: you also have an extra `};` in your MWE

Comment: That was one the sources of the errors. Another error and its solution I have just discovered is added to my question.